# What to do to handle PK overflows?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, overflow, primary-key

What should one do to accommodate the case where a PK could overflow ?

It is unlikely but still possible. I've seen a newsletter opt-out form not function as it probably had many requests.

What can be done on the application side ? What can be done on MySQL ?

Comment: You can use `bigint` if you are worried, which is very unlikely to exceed its maximum

Comment: Yes, that is one practical solution. The keyword here is unlikely. Like Earth suddenly becoming part of an intergalactic federation and having to process the visits of billions of beings from outer space each year :p .

Comment: In real life what can happen is that a database is designed by an outside firm, left as is until the company using it suddenly realizes that something is wrong. Not that unlikely over the space of, say, ten years or more. Which is why I'm curious to see is if someone has had experience tackling this in another way. Say, by retrieving unused PK values, using another table or something different. In ideal conditions, it may be actually be that that an eye is kept during the lifetime of a database and this is something that is handled every now and then by a dev team and database administrator.

Answer (score 3):

> What should one do to accommodate the case where a PK could overflow ?

The simple solution is to design the schema so that the type of the PK is large enough that overflow is not going to happen in any plausible use-case.

If that assumption fails then you have a problem.  I can think of some possible options.

- Change the PK type to a type that is "bigger", modify the application and migrate the data.
- Write an application to "compact" the key space; i.e. for each live key, update all records that use the key replacing it with a new key ... starting from the beginning of the space.
- Wrap the keyspace, and use a more complicated generator for getting the next key that checks that each candidate key is not already in use.

---

Note that this kind of thing is not normally designed into a system, not least because it is difficult to anticipate and difficult to test.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on one case where a 32-bit INT overflowed.  It was because the app was accidentally skipping 1000 values for each successful row insert.  In that case, the app reached the highest signed INT value, and they couldn't take any more inserts on that table.  I was called to help them restructure the table to use a BIGINT primary key.

But of course *before* doing that, we had to change all the foreign keys of referencing tables to use BIGINT too.  Because we wouldn't want to insert a new PK value into the main table that was unable to be referenced by the FK's in other tables.

It should take longer than our lifetimes to exhaust the range of values in a BIGINT -- unless you skip a billion values each time you insert a new row!

I wrote a script called [pk-full-ratio](https://github.com/billkarwin/bk-tools/blob/master/pk-full-ratio.sql) that will examine every AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY in a given database, and calculate how close (percentage-wise) it is to overflowing.